# How to capture GPS co-ordinates from a Microsoft InfoPath form on a mobile device

Tags: vba, mobile

We are looking for a way to capture GPS coords through the Microsoft INFOPATH form which is loaded on our Mobile Motion device.

Basically, we are trying to put a VB script behind the “Get GPS Coord” and possibly
the “Photo & Coordinates” buttons on the “INFOPATH” form that we have developed.
My VB code experience is non-existent but can have programming backgound.

This is the only VB script we have which does not work:

```
DIM ptg AS TGIS_Point 
ptg = GIS.CS.FromWGS( GisPoint( oGPS.Longitude, oGPS.Latitude ) )
dim gisPoint as TGIS_ShapePoint
gisPoint = oLayer.CreateShape(gisShapeTypePoint,0)
gisPoint.AddPart
oPos.SetPosition( ptg, NOTHING, 0 )
gisPoint.AddPoint(ptg)
gisPoint = gisPoint.MakeEditable
gisPoint.IsSelected = TRUE
App.SelectedShapes.Add(gisPoint)
App.ActiveLayer = oLayer
GIS.Update()
GIS_Legend.Update()
GIS_Attributes.Update()
'OPEN CRUISE POINTS FORM HERE 
DIM CruisePointsForm as TForm2
CruisePointsForm = ScriptApp.CreateForm(TForm2.Create(ScriptApp))
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I stopped reading at "VB script" :)

Comment: When you say it doesn't work can you explain the issues that you are running into.  That will help to break down the problem.

Comment: This script was given to me by a work colleague so not sure where he got it from and whether it was meant to be used with InfoPath. Maybe there is a better way to do this than in VB.